# Why we need the condition $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ is torsion free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In Huybrechts' Complex Geometry 3.3 Lefschetz Theorems p134,we have boundary map $c_1:Pic(X)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$.Then we can define *Jacobian* $Pic^0(X)$ is the kernel of the map $c_1$.

We have a corollary(3.3.6):If $X$ is a compact Kahler manifold,then $Pic^0(X)$ is in a natural way a complex torus of dimension $b_1(X)$.

Clearly,the pre-image $Pic^\alpha (X)\subset Pic(X)$ of any element $\alpha\in H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ in the image of $c_1$ can be identified with $Pic^0(X)$,although not canonically.

**Then,we get the claim:Thus,for a compact Kahler manifold,such that $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ is torsion free,the Picard group $Pic(X)$ is fibred by tori of complex dimension $b_1(X)$ over the discrete set $H^{1,1}(X, \mathbb Z)$.**

Here,$$H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)=Im(H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb C))\cap H^{1,1}(X),$$also note that for a compact Kahler manifold.The $Pic(X)\rightarrow H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)$ is surjective.

Hence,we have the diagram:

[image]
My question is:Why we need the condition: $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ is torsion free to get the claim?Can anyone give me some help?Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know the context really, but perhaps it's an application of the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: Note the discussion on the middle of p. 134. "Modulo torsion in $H^2(M,\Bbb Z)$ ... We are only talking about that part of the cohomology that sits in $H^2(M,\Bbb C)$, so torsion disappears.

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin,thanks for your patience and time!